# ISSUE: Reloading a tableView Section hides other tableView sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello all I am stuck in a weird issue, I am reloading a tableViewSection  and it is reloading that section correctly But it hides other section Until I scroll it up or  down. I have used following code for reloading

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 if (ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].collapsed)!{
        return 0
    }
    else{
        return (ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].data.count)! - 1
    }
}
@objc func collapseSection(sender:UIButton)
{
    ObjectDetails?.arrData[sender.tag].collapsed = !(ObjectDetails?.arrData[sender.tag].collapsed)!
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer:sender.tag), with: .none)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Also Note if I write this function with `reloadData()` it works fine But that is slow

```
@objc func collapseSection(sender:UIButton)
{
    ObjectDetails?.arrData[sender.tag].collapsed = !(ObjectDetails?.arrData[sender.tag].collapsed)!
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What does collapsing a section actually do?  Can you show your `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? Do you have variable height cells?  If so, have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRowAt`?

Comment: it  sets number of rows to 0 when collapsed

Comment: i have added code for numberOfRows  check again pleas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Anyone who may go through this issue**

So i have found the solution and according to this I found one thing don't use Reusable view like cell on header view if you are in need to reload sections on any action.
if you are using a cell don't return complete cell just return its contentView.

**Before**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! headerCell
    headerView.lblHeaderName.text = ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].data[0].key.Translate()
    headerView.btnCollapse.tag = section
    headerView.btnCollapse.addTarget(self, action: #selector(collapseSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    if (ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].collapsed)!
    {
         headerView.btnCollapse.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        headerView.btnCollapse.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
    }
    return headerView
}
```

**After**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! headerCell
    headerView.lblHeaderName.text = ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].data[0].key.Translate()
    headerView.btnCollapse.tag = section
    headerView.btnCollapse.addTarget(self, action: #selector(collapseSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    if (ObjectDetails?.arrData[section].collapsed)!
    {
         headerView.btnCollapse.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        headerView.btnCollapse.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
    }
    return headerView.contentView
}
```